# Python regex to match multiple times inside same group

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match a pattern against string that could have multiple instances of similar groups and each group could have multiple instances of similar elements.

example:

```
html_string = '''
..............................
<a>Receive By</a><span>I_AM_INTERESTED_IN_THIS</span>
..............................
<input name="SOMENAME" value="I_AM_INTERESTED_IN_THIS_TOO">
..............................
<input name="SOMENAME" value="I_AM_INTERESTED_IN_THIS_TOO">
..............................
<a>Receive By</a><span>I_AM_INTERESTED_IN_THIS</span>
..............................
<input name="SOMENAME" value="I_AM_INTERESTED_IN_THIS_TOO">
..............................
<a>Receive By</a><span>I_AM_INTERESTED_IN_THIS</span>
..............................
<input name="SOMENAME" value="I_AM_INTERESTED_IN_THIS_TOO">
..............................
<input name="SOMENAME" value="I_AM_INTERESTED_IN_THIS_TOO">
..............................
<input name="SOMENAME" value="I_AM_INTERESTED_IN_THIS_TOO">
..............................
'''

match = re.findall(r'(?:>Receive By</a><span>(.*?)<.*?)?name=\"SOMENAME\" value=\"(.*?)\"', html_string)
```

but I am not getting desired results with 1 regex.
In other words results must be grouped by "Receive By" value containing input values of corresponding group

Comment: use a html parser - not regex,

Comment: [TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7505395)

Comment: As mentioned by @PatrickArtner, using regex is not a recommended solution for parsing HTML, instead use html parser like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely go with that way, but anyway I am interested how could it be achieved with regex. Lets forget that its a HTML.

Comment: Well, no one will forget this is HTML if your question contains HTML snippets. Even if we imagine it is text, how come you expect to find a match in `<a>Receive By</a><span>I_AM_INTERESTED_IN_THIS</span>` if there is no `name=` and `value=` that are required in your pattern?